# Raphael - save attributes of svg element after animation

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, raphael

I am pretty new to Raphael and I want to create a small snake game using purely this library. I tried testing out the animate function to change the cx/cy value of a circle and repeat it (so it keeps going indefinitely). My ultimate goal is to have a listener so that when different arrow keys are pressed, the animation direction changes accordingly, but the movement keeps going. I have the following code:

```
var circle = paper.circle(50, 40, 10);
circle.attr("fill", "#f00");
circle.attr("stroke", "#fff");

var snakeMove = Raphael.animation({cx: circle.attr("cx")+30}, 1000, function(){
    circle.attr("cx", (circle.attr("cx") + 30).toString());
}).repeat(Infinity);
circle.animate(snakeMove);
```

[JsFiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/xzzyetxs/)

However, after the animation completes, the cx value resets to what it was originally. How do I make a repeating change to an svg updated attribute using Raphael? (or any other library suggestion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be tempted to start to break the animation into your own function, rather than using 'animate' alone, as that can be quite constrictive.

So you could just use setInterval and increment the cx attribute in an animation within the setInterval func, then you can do what you want. Eg this would alternate every time you click the circle...

```
 var DIRECTION=1
 setInterval( moveFunc, 1000);

 function moveFunc() {
   circle.animate({ cx: circle.attr('cx')+ 30*DIRECTION  }, 1000)
 }

 circle.click( function() { DIRECTION *= -1 } )
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ian_b/xzzyetxs/5/)